# Windows environment variables. How do I change the name that I must type at command prompt to run a path target

Tags: environment-variables

I am using Windows 10 Pro, but I'm sure the process is the same as Windows Vista through 8.1 or it's similar enough for me to figure out the minor differences.

I have two programs with the same exact named .exe file that I want to target in my path variable in system variables.

Example: Program 1's path: `C:\somefolder\anotherfolder\prog.exe` Program 2's path: `C:\evenmorefolders\prog.exe`

I can't run both just by putting their filepaths in the `PATH` variable because then it will only use the first one listed when I type `prog` in the command prompt.

I want to set one of these programs to be opened with a name other than prog. I want to be able to type say `free` in order to use the `prog.exe` of program 2.

How do I set the environment variables to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two simplest options (that I can think of) to do what you're trying to do don't require changing the PATH environment variable.

Option one, just to get it out of the way, you can create a Windows Shortcut and point it directly at the program you're trying to run.  However, you're asking about typing at a command line, so maybe Shortcuts won't meet your requirements.

Option two, you can create a batch file to run your program.

1. Open Notepad
2. Type in `C:\somefolder\anotherfolder\prog.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5` (the path and filename of your actual program)
3. Click File > Save As...
4. Select a location that's in your PATH environment
5. Call it progA.bat (or whatever makes sense)
6. Make sure to select 'All files (*.*)' next to 'Save as type:'

Repeat it for the other program 'C:\evenmorefolders\prog.exe' and call it progB.bat (or whatever...)

The `%1`, etc. will allow parameters typed in at the command line to pass to the program in the batch file.

Now, from a command line, you can type `progA -a -x -t` to run one of the programs or type `progB /j:100 /p "whatever" /m` to run the other one.

Comment: I had thought about that, but I wanted to be able to use command options as well, such as prog -a or prog file.txt and such as that.

Comment: @Progfram why wouldn't you be able to use command with a batch program?

Comment: Actually, I need to be able to use command options. Defeats the whole purpose if I can't use command options when using it from the command line.

Comment: @Progfram Ah.  See edits in my answer.

Comment: Seems to be working great, but I'm not sure what you meant by the progB /j:100 /p "whatever" /m

Are you just telling me that any of those types of conditions will work with that batch file?

Comment: @Progfram Yes.  those are just made up sample parameters you might use.   Also, you can have up to 9 of the `%1`, `%2`, etc parameter variables.  If you need more, there are some more complicated tricks you have to do.

Comment: I put all the way to %9. I don't think I'll need beyond %1 though.

Thanks a lot.